# NoCredentialsError when connecting to Cognito with Python and boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, boto3

I'm trying to get a simple instance of AWS Cognito running. I've created the federated identity, with a role assigned to both authenticated and unauthenticated users. I'm trying to connect to the identity in Python but I receive the error:

NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

I'm definitely using the right IdentityId since I copied it directly from the code examples AWS console generates for you. I'm using the following code:

```
import boto3
identity = boto3.client('cognito-identity', 
                        region_name='us-east-1')

response = identity.describe_identity(IdentityId='us-east-1:XXXX')
print (response['IdentityId'])
```

If I instead try to retrieve credentials I get the following error:

ClientError: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetCredentialsForIdentity operation: Identity 'us-east-1:XXXXXX' not found.

Using this code:

```
import boto3
identity = boto3.client('cognito-identity', 
                        region_name='us-east-1')

response = identity.get_credentials_for_identity(IdentityId='us-east-1:XXXXX')
access_key = response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
secret_key = response['Credentials']['SecretKey']

print (access_key)
print (secret_key)
```

I should also note that if I create the identity client using an access key and secret I still get the second error described here, but in both scenarios. As far as I know I should need to provide these credentials, but I've tried anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cognito console doesn't generate an identity id for you, it generates an identity **pool** id. If you're using that as the identity id, that would be the issue, it won't find it. In that case, you would need to generate an identity id (using the GetId API) and use that instead, and use that id to get credentials.

Comment: do you happen to know how to then use the retrieved credentials to call the API Gateway using Python? I'm hoping the boto3 library has a way of taking care of this signing process, but I'm not having much luck with my other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336286/how-do-i-call-an-api-gateway-with-cognito-credentials-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @jeff-bailey great answer, here is a full sample code on how to achieve the author's request:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('cognito-identity', region_name='eu-west-1')

identity_pool_id = 'eu-west-1:a2342392-1391-191-1111111'
response = client.get_id(AccountId='7778718191', IdentityPoolId=identity_pool_id)

identity_id = response['IdentityId']
print("Federated identity id:", identity_id)

response = client.get_credentials_for_identity(IdentityId=identity_id)
access_key = response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
secret_key = response['Credentials']['SecretKey']

print(access_key, secret_key)
```