# How do I call an API Gateway with Cognito credentials in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, boto3

I've managed to setup an API Gateway secured with Cognito. The unauthenticated user role has an access policy that should grant it access to the gateway. I've also managed to use boto3 to retrieve an identity ID from the pool and obtain the associated open ID token, as well as the associated secret and access keys.

How do I now make a call to the gateway using these credentials? Is there a way to use boto3 to handle signing a request to a particular method on the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from our public docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

Cognito creds are no different than any other temporary creds, and the signing process is also the same. If you want to move back to Python the example above should be good, or I would guess that there are third-party libraries out there to do the signature for you.

Comment: Is there a feature in the works to add the ability to generate a Python SDK for API Gateway, as is currently the case for OSX, Android and Javascript? I had seen the example docs you provided but it was ultimately too verbose to be bothered with when the Javascript SDK satisfied the immediate requirements. I'll have a look for an existing sigv4 library for Python though. Do I follow this section and use the Authentication headers to then call the methods on the API Gateway http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html#sig-v4-examples-get-auth-header

Comment: Yep it's on our backlog, eventually we want to support the same SDKs that AWS publishes for services, but there is no ETA for that. In terms of rolling your own, yes you can lift the signing library out of an existing Python SDK and just change the service name to 'execute-api'

Comment: @LaserJesus: I take it your answer, a couple of months later, uses the API Jack said was in the works? If so, I would vote that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

My code is based largely on the questioner's own answer, but I've tried to make it clearer where all the values come from.

```
import boto3
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
# Use 'pip install boto3 requests requests-aws4auth' to get these

region_name = 'ap-southeast-2' # or 'us-west-1' or whatever

# 12 decimal digits from your AWS login page
account_id = '123456789012'

# I've only found this in the sample code for other languages, e.g. JavaScript
# Services→Cognito→Manage Federated Identities→(your-id-pool)→Sample code
identity_pool_id = 'ap-southeast-2:fedcba98-7654-3210-1234-56789abcdef0'

# Create a new identity
boto3.setup_default_session(region_name = region_name)
identity_client = boto3.client('cognito-identity', region_name=region_name)
identity_response = identity_client.get_id(AccountId=account_id,
    IdentityPoolId=identity_pool_id)

# We normally wouldn't log this, but to illustrate:
identity_id = identity_response['IdentityId']
print ('identity_id:', identity_id) # good idea not to log this

# Get the identity's credentials
credentials_response = identity_client.get_credentials_for_identity(IdentityId=identity_id)
credentials = credentials_response['Credentials']
access_key_id = credentials['AccessKeyId']
secret_key = credentials['SecretKey']
service = 'execute-api'
session_token = credentials['SessionToken']
expiration = credentials['Expiration']
# Again, we normally wouldn't log this:
print ('access_key_id', access_key_id)
print ('secret_key', secret_key)
print ('session_token', session_token)
print ('expiration', expiration)
# The access_key_id will look something like 'AKIABC123DE456FG7890', similar to
# Services→IAM→Users→(AWS_USER_NAME)→Security credentials→Access key ID

# Get the authorisation object
auth = AWS4Auth(access_key_id, secret_key, region_name, service,
    session_token=session_token)
current_app['auth'] = auth
# Just an illustration again:
print ('auth: %(service)s(%(date)s) %(region)s:%(access_id)s' % auth.__dict__)

# We'll use that object to send a request to our app. This app doesn't
# exist in real life, though, so you'll need to edit the following quite
# heavily:

# Services→Cognito→Manage your User Pools→(your-user-pool)→Apps→App name
app_name = 'my-app-name'

api_path = 'dev/helloworld'
method = 'GET'
headers = {}
body = ''
url = 'https://%s.%s.%s.amazonaws.com/%s' % (app_name, service, region_name,
    api_path)
response = requests.request(method, url, auth=auth, data=body, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you for documenting the ID values. That hung up me too. Unfortunately, this code doesn't work for user pools, only identity pools.

Answer (score 4):

The following code (and the requests-aws4auth library) did the job:

```
import boto3
import datetime
import json
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
import requests

boto3.setup_default_session(region_name='us-east-1')
identity = boto3.client('cognito-identity', region_name='us-east-1')

account_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
identity_pool_id='us-east-1:YYY-YYYY-YYY-YY'
api_prefix='ZZZZZZZZZ'

response = identity.get_id(AccountId=account_id, IdentityPoolId=identity_pool_id)
identity_id = response['IdentityId']
print ("Identity ID: %s"%identity_id)

resp = identity.get_credentials_for_identity(IdentityId=identity_id)
secretKey = resp['Credentials']['SecretKey']
accessKey = resp['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
sessionToken = resp['Credentials']['SessionToken']
expiration = resp['Credentials']['Expiration']

print ("\nSecret Key: %s"%(secretKey))
print ("\nAccess Key %s"%(accessKey))
print ("\nSession Token: %s"%(sessionToken))
print ("\nExpiration: %s"%(expiration))

method = 'GET'
headers = {}
body = ''
service = 'execute-api'
url = 'https://%s.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/helloworld' % api_prefix
region = 'us-east-1'

auth = AWS4Auth(accessKey, secretKey, region, service, session_token=sessionToken)
response = requests.request(method, url, auth=auth, data=body, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Where does the api_prefix come from? Thanks!

Comment: @Efren I believe it's something you can find in the AWS console when you access the management section for your API gateway application, i.e. <your api prefix>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com . When in the managment area, click on the resources section on the left, then click on one of the endpoints in your gateway, i.e. /pets, the full URL including the prefix will appear on the right

Comment: Could you describe where to get the other values from too, please? I'm sure it's obvious for people who've been using AIM for longer than I, but this code isn't working for me, so I'm probably getting `account_id` and `api_prefix` from the wrong place. I'm not even sure if my `identity_pool_id` is right; when I go to User Pools→Pool Details→Pool Id, mine has an underscore in it, not a colon like in your example (and like in the docs at http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-identity.html#CognitoIdentity.Client.get_id)

Comment: I eventually got it working. My main confusion was between user pools and identity pools. I've posted my own answer, which hopefully makes it clearer where to get the required values.

Answer (score 1):

Next code is working really well.

Hope to help:

```py
from pprint import pprint
import requests
from pycognito import Cognito


USER_POOL_ID = 'eu-central-1_XXXXXXXXXXX'
CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'

u = Cognito(USER_POOL_ID,CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, username='cognito user name')
u.authenticate('cognito user password')

id_token = u.id_token

headers = {'Authorization':  'Bearer ' + id_token}
api_url = 'https://XXXXXXXXXXX.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/stage/XXXXXXXXXXX'

r = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
pprint(dict(r.headers))
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

identity_pool_id how to get

If you have not federated pool which could give you "identity_pool_id" ,
execution code below will give you identity_pool_id

```
import boto3
boto3.setup_default_session(
    aws_access_key_id='AKIAJ7TBC72BPWNEWIDQ', 
    aws_secret_access_key='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', 
    region_name='ap-southeast-2')

client = boto3.client('cognito-identity')
response = client.list_identity_pools(MaxResults=3,)

print("IdentityPoolId-- ", response)
```