# Using Amazon Boto3 to get REST API URL

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-requests, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I am kind of confused as you how I use the Api Gateway's in AWS. I have an existing Api that I want to get the actual URL call for using [boto3 for ApiGateway's](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html)

I would expect something like,

```
import boto3, requests

client = boto3.client('apigateway', <Auth tokens>)
response = requests.get(client.get_rest_url(PHYSICAL_ID_OF_API),
                        json={...}, auth=client.get_auth(PHYSICAL_ID_OF_API))
```

I am having a hard time parsing the docs.

Comment: What response are you looking for? The endpoint? e.g. `https://${api_id}.execute-api.${region}.amazonaws.com/${stage}/${resource}`

Comment: That and how you work with security credentials.

Comment: Hi, you can find an example of how to invoke API Gateway using signed requests in this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336286/how-do-i-call-an-api-gateway-with-cognito-credentials-in-python